# Doctrine query outside the controller Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I have some trouble since two days to do a query using a UserRepository outside a controller. I am trying to get a user from the database from a class that I named ApiKeyAuthenticator. I want to execute the query in the function getUsernameForApiKey like in the docs. I think I am suppose to use donctrine as a service but I don't get how to do this.

Thanks for you help in advance!

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Security/ApiKeyUserProvider.php
namespace AppBundle\Security;
    
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class ApiKeyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        // Look up the username based on the token in the database, via
        // an API call, or do something entirely different
        $username = ...;

        return $username;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return new User(
            $username,
            null,
            // the roles for the user - you may choose to determine
            // these dynamically somehow based on the user
            array('ROLE_API')
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // this is used for storing authentication in the session
        // but in this example, the token is sent in each request,
        // so authentication can be stateless. Throwing this exception
        // is proper to make things stateless
        throw new UnsupportedUserException();
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your `ApiKeyUserProvider` a service and inject the `UserRepository` as a dependency. Not sure if repositories are services in 2.8, so maybe you'll have to inject the `EntityManager` .

```
class ApiKeyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository(User::class);
        // ...
```

Now register your class as a service in your services.yml file

```
services:
    app.api_key_user_provider:
        class:     AppBundle\Security\ApiKeyUserProvider
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```